# Logitech headset not working with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, logitech-headset

I have a Logitech H110 headset (USB).  For some reason it is not working with Windows 7.

When I plug it in, Windows tries to download the driver, but there isn't any. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

Go to Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound
In next to the Sound subhead in the main pane, choose Manage Audio Devices
and then click the Recording tab.
Click, then Right-click on the Microphone.
Click Listen on the popup that will come up by following preceding step.
Then check Listen to this Device and Click Appl

Comment: theres no manage audio devices in my control panal.

Comment: @vembutech -1 OP clearly described that driver is not installed for his device. Device without driver installed will not show anywhere in windows, let alone in Recording tab.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

- plug in the device
- go to start
- type "control panel"
- open control panel
- click "device manager"
- look for "other devices"
- expand that and right click on the one that has the name of your device
- click delete or uninstall
- unplug the device
- wait for 30 seconds
- plug in the device
- wait for the device to be found and for the drivers to be installed
- after the install is done it will say "Your device is ready"

  ```
                                        -**WARNINGS**
  ```
- FALLOW INSTRUCTIONS TO THE LETTER
- DO NOT MOVE OR REMOVE THE USB PLUG WITHOUT A PROMPT
- DO NOT CLICK ANY BUTTONS ON THE DEVICE UNLESS PROMPTED
- JUST LET IT WORK
- IN THE FUTURE, ALWAYS USE THE SAME USB PORT BECAUSE IT WILL TRY TO INSTALL DRIVERS FOR THE SAME DEVICE EVEN IF IT WAS INSTALLED BEFORE WILE IN A DIFFERNT USB PORT

Comment: Please don't yell (no need for all those uppercases ...)